# How do I properly structure AWS Lambda Python Layer to avoid Import Errors?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a custom python layer in AWS Lambda with the structure:

```
/python
|_/m_utilities
  |_/functions
    |_/__init__.py
    |_/Defaults.py
    |_/Athena.py
  |_/parameterizer
    |_/classes
      |_/__init__.py
      |_/AthenaLite.py
      |_/BaseParameter.py
    |_/__init__.py
|_/misc
```

- The parameterizer init.py contains `from parameterizer.classes.AthenaLite import athena_parameterizer as athena_lite`

The lambda handler starts with:

```
from m_utilities.functions.Athena import <various functions>
from m_utilities.parameterizer import athena_lite
```

This structure works as expected locally, I'm able to import everything with no issues. When I attempt to test the lambda however I get the error: *[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'parameterizer'*

When attempting to debug, one of the things I tried was editing the lambda handler to examine the folder structure (which looks correct) and printing off the modules within the *m_utilities* package to see if my 'parameterizer' module exists there.

This in the lambda handler:

```
try:
    from m_utilities.parameterizer import athena_lite
except:
    import os.path, pkgutil,m_utilities
    pkgpath = os.path.dirname(fp_utilities.__file__)
    print([name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([pkgpath])])
```

Returns in AWS:

```
['functions', 'messaging', 'parameterizer', 'misc']
```

The module appears to be there, so what am I doing incorrectly that it is unable to import it?

Comment: Are you sure that in the layer the `parameterizer` folder has an `__init.py__` ?

Comment: Yes, and to double check I edited the handler to print off everything in the 'parameterizer' folder and it returned: '/opt/python/utilities/parameterizer/__init__.py' and '/opt/python/utilities/parameterizer/classes'

Comment: I'm really at a loss here. I may try separating the modules into different layers but I was hoping to have a consolidated package I could maintain easier.

Comment: How did you package the layers?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I'm not sure why, this structure worked in AWS:

```
/python
|_/m_utilities
  |_/functions
    |_/__init__.py
    |_/Defaults.py
    |_/Athena.py
|_/parameterizer
  |_/classes
    |_/__init__.py
    |_/AthenaLite.py
    |_/BaseParameter.py
  |_/__init__.py
|_/misc
```

I moved the '*parameterizer*' module into the top-level folder, and `from parameterizer import athena_lite` worked.